# How can i send my recipe from chef workstation to chef node without using chef server?

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I am using traditional method by uploading cookbook to chef server and then attaching run list with chef node. I have already bootstrapped my node via workstation.

Answer (score 0):

You're best bet is probably [knife-zero](https://knife-zero.github.io) being you use workstation. There was [knife-solo](http://matschaffer.github.io/knife-solo/) back in the day, but my guess is you want a way to run `chef-run`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer..knife-zero helped to upload recipe to node without uploading it to server.